# What is the use of the pipe symbol in YAML?

Tags: yaml

I am new to yaml, and I have a question about the pipe symbol (|) used for multiple lines. Does YAML have any syntax like the one below?

> test: ***|6+***

Of the two YAML files below, the first one is working and second is not. I do not know what is causing this.

**First File**

```
Name :
  -
   testing:
     val1
  -
   second:
     val2
  -
   third:
     val3
  -
   then
  - 
    final: |
     a
     aa
     aaa
     aaaa : 'test:'
```

**Second File**

```
Name :
  -
   testing:
     val1
  -
   second:
     val2
  -
   third:
     val3
  -
   then
  - 
    final: |6+
      a
      aa
      aaa
      aaaa : 'test:'
```

The second file is the customer's.

I am using XMLBeans and I get this error:

> **com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.parser.Parser$ParserException: Line 17, column 12: Expected a 'block end' but found: block mapping start"**.

Answer (score 344):

The pipe symbol at the end of a line in YAML signifies that any indented text that follows should be interpreted as a multi-line scalar value.  See [the YAML spec](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2795688).

Specifically, the pipe indicates that (except for the indentation) the scalar value should be interpreted literally in such a way that preserves newlines.  Conversely, the `>` character indicates that multi-line "folded" scalar follows, meaning that newlines are converted to spaces.  For example:

```python
>>> import yaml
>>> yaml.load("""
... |
...  This is a multi-line
...  literal style scalar.
... """)
'This is a multi-line\nliteral style scalar.\n'
>>> yaml.load("""
... >
...  This is a multi-line
...  folded scalar; new lines are folded into
...  spaces.
... """)
'This is a multi-line folded scalar; new lines are folded into spaces.\n'
```

The `6+` part is the indentation indicator (an explicit specification of how many spaces of indentation should be used) with the "chomping indicator" `+` which controls how extra whitespace at the end of the scalar literal should be handled.

The error you're getting is a tricky one: It's because indentation should be relative to the current block-level element.  So in this case it should be `2+` instead of `6+` because the last block-level element is the mapping `final:` and the literal is indented 2 from it.  Updated with correction from @bramvi.

Comment: Also look at [in-yaml-how-do-i-break-a-string-over-multiple-lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/in-yaml-how-do-i-break-a-string-over-multiple-lines)

Comment: `So in this case it should be 4+ instead of 6+` I think it should be 2, not 4, because that's the relative indent there. Tested on `pyyaml 6.0`.

Comment: @bravmi Good catch.  8+ years of this answer and no one pointed that out before.  I agree.

Comment: I don't recall why I made the justification for `4+` based on `final:` not being a block element.  It clearly is.  It's not a flow-style mapping without the `{ ... }`.

Comment: Def. multi-line scalar: a multi-line string of dynamic size. In javascript, this is just known as a string.
 https://eemeli.org/yaml-playground/

Answer (score 43):

The pipe is used when you want newlines to be kept as newlines.

For more information : https://yaml-multiline.info/