# using custom command, pipe and nested quotes in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

I am using a container that allows to pass a command to be run during the entrypoint : the entrypoint does an `exec $@`.

I would like to run this command to add a line at the end of the config file :

```
cat /etc/program/config.yaml | grep "include: custom-config.yaml" || echo "include: custom-config.yaml" >> /etc/program/config.yaml
```

I'm trying to use it in `docker-compose.yml` like that :

```
command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "'cat /etc/program/config.yaml | grep ''include: custom-config.yaml'' || echo ''include: custom-config.yaml'' >> /etc/program/config.yaml '"]
```

but this doesn't works

```
/etc/program/config.yaml: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
/etc/program/config.yaml: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/etc/program/config.yaml: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
/etc/program/config.yaml: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
...
```

I think it might be caused by the pipe (see [What is the use of the pipe symbol in YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540635/what-is-the-use-of-the-pipe-symbol-in-yaml)), but I haven't been able to fix it

Thanks

Comment: I may be ignorant about something but why the doubled single quotes `''` like in `... grep ''include...` ?

Comment: It seems that it's the way to escape single quotes in single-quoted strings in yaml

Comment: But your strings are double-quoted. And it seems like you forgot the `cat` command at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally created a script like that :

```
#!/bin/bash

cat /etc/program/config.yaml | grep "include: custom-config.yaml" || echo "include: custom-config.yaml" >> /etc/program/config.yaml

/docker-entrypoint.sh
```

and used it in the docker-compose file

```
entrypoint: /new_entrypoint.sh
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to create a script name `run.sh` like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cat /etc/program/config.yaml | grep "include: custom-config.yaml" || echo "include: custom-config.yaml" >> /etc/program/config.yaml
```

Then create a docker file like the following:

```
FROM {{SOME_IMAGE}}

# ... some instructions ...

COPY run.sh .
CMD [ "run.sh" ]
```

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately I don't have the liberty to create a new image, that's why i'm trying to workaround the existing one

Comment: You say that cannot create a new image, but you want to fix the issue. In order to that, despite of the solution, you have to recreate the image. Or am I missing something?