# How do you specify a pattern to match multiple files for Azure Devops json variable substitution?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am using the AzureRMWebAppDeployment@4 task to deploy a logic app using an Azure Devops yaml pipeline. I want to update values in both the host.json and appsettings.json files using json variable substitution.

According to the documentation, the JSONFiles parameter can accept "a newline-separated list of json files to substitute the variable values". How can I specify that?

I have tried the following:

```
            - task: AzureRMWebAppDeployment@4
              inputs:
                ...
                JSONFiles: '**/parameters.json
                  **/host.json'
```

and also the following:

```
                JSONFiles: '**/parameters.json|**/host.json'
```

There must be something simple I'm missing.
How do I specify a pattern which matches two or more files by name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `|` should work.
From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61661091/4167200):

> The pipe symbol at the end of a line in YAML signifies that any indented text that follows should be interpreted as a multi-line scalar value. See the [YAML spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2-old/spec.html#id2795688).

So in you case it should be something like that:

```yaml
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    ...
    JSONFiles: |
     **/parameters.json
     **/host.json
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Knew it had to be something simple! I need to learn more YAML.