# Meaning of pipe operator in a specific case in an ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

In the below block of an ansible playbook, what is the meaning of the `|` *pipe* operator followed by `bool` ? 
I get what they mean separately, but here it does not seem to make any sense to me. Why would one need to interpret a `bool` as a mutli-line value ?

> The pipe symbol at the end of a line in YAML signifies that any indented text that follows should be interpreted as a multi-line scalar value. See the YAML spec. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18708156/8325852

```
- name: Remove default nginx vhost config file (if configured).
  file:
    path: "{{ nginx_default_vhost_path }}"
    state: absent
  when: nginx_remove_default_vhost | bool
  notify: restart nginx
```

Comment: You are confusing the pipe operator inside an ansible jinja2 expression to apply filters and the multiline yaml literal scalar block type indicator (see https://yaml-multiline.info/). In this later case it should be present right after a key defintion following the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just force the type to bool.

here the docs about it https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#forcing-the-data-type