# Difference of Double Quotes and Vertical bar in yaml

Tags: python, yaml

I'm writing a Python script that creates a YAML file according to DataFrame and I came across this:

```
test:
   query: |
      create or replace view emp as

      select e.id as emp_id
      from employees as e
```

vs

```
test:
   query: "create or replace view emp\nas\nselect e.id\
    \                        as emp_id\n       FROM employees\n
   as e\
   \n;"
```

Are they technically the same or am I missing something? If they are not the same, how do I make the second version like the first that uses a vertical bar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the use of the pipe symbol in YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540635/what-is-the-use-of-the-pipe-symbol-in-yaml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are technically not the same, but they are similar, as you can see by loading them:

```py
import ruamel.yaml

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe', pure=True)
for fn in 'literal.yaml', 'quoted.yaml':
    data = yaml.load(Path(fn))
    print(repr(data['test']['query']))
```

which gives:

```
'create or replace view emp as\n\nselect e.id as emp_id\nfrom employees as e\n'
'create or replace view emp\nas\nselect e.id                        as emp_id\n       FROM employees\n as e\n;'
```

The double quoted style can represent any string using backslash escapes, but is not always very readable.

If you have a string with just linebreaks, you can often use the first form, called a [literal
style scalar](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.1/#id2795688).

You can create individual literal style scalars using the following (of course you don't have to start from
loaded data, you can just as well create that in YAML):

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml.scalarstring import LiteralScalarString as LS

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(Path('quoted.yaml'))
data['test']['query'] =  LS(data['test']['query'])
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
test:
  query: |-
    create or replace view emp
    as
    select e.id                        as emp_id
           FROM employees
     as e
    ;
```

Comment: is there a way to remove the "-" after "|" ? such that it looks something like this query: |

Comment: @jun That dash after the pipe is the standard YAML chomping operator. It is there because the string loaded from the second example doesn't end in a newline but in a semicolon `;`. Add something like `if data['test']['query'][-1] != '\n': data['test']['query'] += '\n'`