# Dump a list in Python dict into YAML file as examples

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I have a Python dict as below and I want to dump it into a YAML file. I want to dump those examples as a list of string examples instead of individual key (There is a pipe `|` after `examples`. How can I do that?

```
data = {'version': '1.0',
 'food': [{'category': 'japanese', 'examples': ['sushi', 'ramen', 'sashimi']},
 {'category': 'chinese', 'examples': ['hotpot', 'noodle', 'fried rice']}]}

yaml.SafeDumper.ignore_aliases = lambda *args : True
with open('food.yml', 'w', encoding = "utf-8") as yaml_file:
    dump = yaml.safe_dump(data,
                          default_flow_style=False,
                          allow_unicode=False,
                          encoding=None,
                          sort_keys=False,
                          line_break=10)
    yaml_file.write(dump)
```

*Result*

```
version: '1.0'
food:
- category: japanese
  examples:
  - sushi
  - ramen
  - sashimi
- category: chinese
  examples:
  - hotpot
  - noodle
  - fried rice
```

*Expected*

```
version: '1.0'
food:
- category: japanese
  examples: |
    - sushi
    - ramen
    - sashimi
- category: chinese
  examples: |
    - hotpot
    - noodle
    - fried rice
```

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/q/15540635/3216427 the pipe symbol is not for lists, but for multi-line text strings. So to get your expected results, you would have to have multi-line strings, and that's not what you have.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/3790454/3216427

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructs with `|` are [literal style scalars](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.1/#id2795688).
And within its indented context the leading dashes have no special meaning (i.e. the are
**not** parsed as block style sequence indicators).
PyYAML doesn't support those literal scalars on individual strings without adding representers.

PyYAML only supports a subset of YAML 1.1
and that specification was superseded in 2009. The recommended extension for files containing
YAML documents has been `.yaml` since at least [September 2006](https://web.archive.org/w
eb/20060924190202/http://yaml.org/faq.html).

It is not clear why you use these outdated libraries and conventions, but it looks like it is time to upgrade:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

def literal(*args):
    # convert args to a multiline string that looks like block sequence
    # convert to string in case non-strings were passed in
    return ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.LiteralScalarString(
               '- ' + '\n- '.join([str(x) for x in args]) + '\n'
           )   

data = {'version': '1.0',
 'food': [{'category': 'japanese', 'examples': literal('sushi', 'ramen', 'sashimi')},
 {'category': 'chinese', 'examples': literal('hotpot', 'noodle', 'fried rice')}]}

    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
version: '1.0'
food:
- category: japanese
  examples: |
    - sushi
    - ramen
    - sashimi
- category: chinese
  examples: |
    - hotpot
    - noodle
    - fried rice
```